# linux shell how many loop various

Tags: python, linux, shell, sh

Linux shell has so many loops syntax and how to choice it!

```
while read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
done < input.file
```

```
for line in `cat a.txt`; do
  echo "$line"
while
```

and so on

Comment: Why not run it with some example files and see what it does? A key difference will be very obvious if you just test it out a bit yourself.

Comment: Try it you will see!  Put this in your input.file or a.txt:  **line 1** a b c **line 2** defg  **line 3** g h.  You will see the difference in how it manages lines and space separated text.  Couple syntax points: **a** no need for `;` **b** to execute your `cat`, do this instead `$(cat a.txt)`.

Comment: This one is easy: [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a test yourself, such as

write a file test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
        printf("hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

and then using the two command

A: while read -r line;do echo $line; done < test.c

you will get this result

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
printf("hello world
");
return 0;
}
```

and B: for line in `cat test.c`;do echo $line;done

you get the result like this:

```
#include
<stdio.h>
int
main(void){
printf("hello
world
");
return
0;
}
```

and now you will find the differences.